# Logic for call a function one time only in each 24 hour or in a day in java

Tags: java

i have one function

```
callEach24hourOneTime();
```

i have to call this function in each 24 hour only one time within 24 once it will executed then i don't have to call callEach24hourOneTime

i am unable to get current time hour minute and second in millis so that i can apply condition i tried below logic but unable to execute.

```
if(currentmillis=86400000 ){
 callEach24hourOneTime(); 
}
else {
//dont call do other operation
}
```

please suggest me solution for this .

Comment: Java EE has included schedulers, for Java SE you may rely on cron.

Comment: Please do not suggest that this is a C, C# or C++ question.  You only appear to be trying to game the system here.

Comment: First, `=` is an assignment operator, so that code won't compile. Use the `==` equality operator. --- Second, the probability of executing that `if` statement after *exactly* 24 hours, *to the millisecond*, is highly unlikely. Use `currentmillis >= 86400000`

Comment: If this is java then why the c#, c++, and c tags?

Comment: You can use a timer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Comment: @paparazzo i want logic not its java specific

Comment: @Andreas  current time millisecond i want to get only for Hour

Comment: @aka-one i cant use Timer because time each time executing  i am trying with logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logic to always have **at least 24 hours** between executions of the `callEach24hourOneTime()` method:

```
private long nextCallMillis;
```

```
long currentMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (currentMillis >= this.nextCallMillis) {
    this.nextCallMillis = currentMillis + 86400000/*24 hours*/;
    callEach24hourOneTime();
} else {
    // ...
}
```

That will cause a drift in time-of-day for the execution of the method. The speed of the drift is determined by how often the code is execute.

If you instead want method to be called at (around) the **same time every day**:

```
private long nextCallMillis;
```

```
long currentMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (this.nextCallMillis == 0)
    this.nextCallMillis = currentMillis; // Establish time-of-day
if (currentMillis >= this.nextCallMillis) {
    this.nextCallMillis += ((currentMillis - this.nextCallMillis) / 86400000 + 1) * 86400000;
    callEach24hourOneTime();
} else {
    // ...
}
```

"Same time every day" is in UTC, so when crossing Daylight Savings Time changes, the time-of-day will change by 1 hour.

---

**UPDATE**

If you just want "once per day" logic:

```
private LocalDate lastCallDate;
```

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
if (! today.equals(lastCallDate)) {
    this.lastCallDate = today;
    callOnceDailyOneTime();
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: i execute code but it always execute if condition it never goes else @Andreas

Comment: @AnilThakur Are you sure the field value `nextCallMillis` is retained between calls? Logic works fine. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/OgX90g) for accelerated demo (once per second instead of once per 24 hours).

Comment: i think nextCallMillis  we need save some where in locally but in that case i need to   set when date change then we have set nextCallMillis  again 0 can you please suggest me @Andreas

Comment: @AnilThakur Why would you need to "set nextCallMillis again 0"? Do you even understand what the value of `System.currentTimeMillis()` means? The entire point of the code is to remember when (time of day) the method was called, so it can be called again at that time of day, **once per 24 hour period**. If you clear the value "when date change", then what's the point of any of it?

Comment: and one more thing if i will change date we have to reset nextCallMillis call value to 0

Comment: after save nextCallMillis in locally its working properly but only one test case fail when i change date then  i have to reset to 0 of nextCallMillis value so that i can recall callEach24hourOneTime  @Andreas

Comment: @AnilThakur If you reset value to 0 when date change, then method will be called first time each day, so likely right after midnight. Is that what you want, because it is certainly not what the question says you want. "Once per day" and "once every 24 hours" is **not** the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can you a cron library.

I don't really know what language or framework you are currently using, but from spring I'd say you can use @Scheduled :

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * *")
  private void myMethod(){}
```

For exemple the cron above will make myMethod() execute once a day.

Comment: i dont have to use any library  i have write function based on Logic @HypnoZ